# change color of a word while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to assign a color for a word. so when somebody types the word.. the word, immediately, goes into the color that I assigned for it. I have looked everywhere in the net, and I could not find any example or a way of doing it. Is it possible to be done?

For example, If I have I have a blank input

```
<input type="text"/>
```

when I type the word "facebook" I want the word to be turned to blue after inputting the last letter. 
I want it to be done using jQuery or plain JavaScript language. I can change the color of the word after submitting the input by searching the string and adding my style configuration, but I do not want that.. I want an immediate change of the letter without submitting the input.

If it is "impossible" why http://ckeditor.com/demo can assign different color for a specific word.

Comment: You can't change the color of parts of the value in an input.

Comment: So you want to change the colour of the text in the `input` element to change if the `input` element contains the word `"Facebook"`?

Comment: @adeneo can I assign a color for each letter in an input?

Comment: Nope, you can only change the color of all the text

Comment: @lonesomeday yes that is what I want

Comment: @adeneo: but! You could create an element with the same text as the input, match the font, position it precisely over the input’s actual text, and make all its text apart from the given word have a color of transparent! Of course, you’d have to amend the position as the input’s content scrolls when the user inputs more content, which will probably vary from browser-to-browser. Can’t be *that* hard though.

Comment: @shnisaka: Your question implies that you want the word “facebook” to be blue, but any other text in the input should not be blue. E.g. if the user types “What’s Facebook then?” into the input, “Facebook” should be blue, but “What’s” and “then?” should not be.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - if another element was on top of the input, how would you focus the input (tip: pointer events), but you are correct, can have element below or ontop, and fake it, but it's hard to get it right cross browser.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite that is correct

Comment: shnisaka: thanks for confirming. As @adeneo says, you can’t do that.

Comment: @adeneo: ah yes, very good point. You might need to add some event handlers to the element, in case `pointer-events` wasn’t supported.

Comment: updated the question. please read the last line.

Comment: @shnisaka: because the visible content area of ckeditor isn’t a `<textarea>`. It’s an iframe with an HTML document in it. I was going to suggest customising an editor like that to replace your text field actually, but I didn’t know any by name.

Comment: Regarding the update, the reason CKEditor can do that is that they're using `contenteditable` on an `iframe` element. You can't have a simple `input type="text"` element display rich text.

Comment: So, why don't you just use CKEditor or TinyMCE and strip out all the chrome??

Comment: @shnisaka: You could use ckeditor’s approach yourself, by hiding the `<input>` off-screen, putting a `<span>` tag or something in its place, and updating that span whenever the input’s content changes. Here’s a starter for that: http://jsfiddle.net/kaTd3/ The tricky thing is getting the replacement span to both look *and* behave like a native input.

Comment: Instead of picking the color like CkEditor do. I want the colors of the words to be assigned in an HTML file. that way, if somebody is typing these words.. the color of these words will change immediately without letting the user to assign a color for the word himself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with just a simple `<input type="text">`, you need a `contenteditable` `div` or other element. Here's an example of what you want:

HTML:

```
<div id="stuffdiv" contenteditable>
user types here...
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="whateva" id="submittext">
```

JavaScript:

```
var sDiv=document.getElementById('stuffdiv');
sDiv.onkeypress=function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        //the setTimeout is so the content is inserted before execution
        document.getElementById('submittext').value=sDiv.textContent;
        if(sDiv.innerHTML.indexOf('facebook')!==-1){
            sDiv.innerHTML=sDiv.innerHTML.replace('facebook','<span style="color:blue">face<span></span>book</span>');
        }
    },50);
}
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/Jwh9R/1/

Comment: I will accept this answer because this is the closest thing that I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to change the whole word...

```
$('input').keyup(function(){

    var $input = $(this);

    $input.css({
        color: ($input.val().toLowerCase() == 'facebook') ? 'blue' : 'inherit'
    });

});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vTSDk/2/

If you want to match 'Facebook' (case-insensitive) anywhere in the text, use:

```
color: ($input.val().match(/Facebook/i)) ? 'blue' : 'inherit'
```

Comment: Not perfect, but a good approach. the problem is, that it will change the input of everything that is typed with facebook. "what is facebook?" will be all blue. What I want is coloring only one word "facebook"

Comment: @shnisaka: and, as we’ve told you already, *that can’t be done*.